# np.where, np.busday_count() with pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, nan

I am having a bit of trouble tying together the following chain of logic:

```
np.where(df['date3'].isnull(), np.busday_count(df['date2'], df['date1'], holidays=my_holidays), 
np.busday_count(df['date3'], df['date1'], holidays=my_holidays))
```

and here is a sample:

```
date1       date2       date3
2019-01-31  2019-02-01  None
2019-01-31  2019-02-01  None
2019-02-28  2018-10-03  2019-02-28
2019-02-28  2018-10-03  2019-02-28
2019-02-28  2018-10-03  2019-02-28
```

Brief background - the date3 column has some null values. I've tried converting to datetime, then running this function with .dt.date after each date column. I've tried in the way above where the dates are something of the sort "2019-01-31". Both give me a `ValueError: Cannot compute a business day count with a NaT (not-a-time) date when trying from the string versions of the dates`, `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer when trying after converting to datetime`.

From reading online, it seems the issue is arising due to the null values in the one date column, whether I keep as a string and the null is None, or when I convert to datetime where the nulls become `NaT`, a pandas syntactical sugar, in combination with the `np.where()` function.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this? Ideally, I'd try to avoid a for loop due to the time required to loop through the entire dataframe.

I was able to accomplish this via brute force, but I'd like to know how to implement this without looping through the whole dataframe.

Comment: Pls post sample of your dataframe

Comment: sure thing, I added it to the post

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: added the error messages

Comment: From the data you posted it looks like it is not NaN(Null) but 'None' text.
Please check

Comment: Hi gtomer, as stated I tried both avenues. If you convert the date column into a datetime via pd.to_datetime(), naturally those values will become NaT. Either way I get a ValueError.

Answer (score -1):

I' am facing the same issue, when i want to use the busday_count() function, even if i am using the when() function, it seems to apply to the full column anyways and fails because the Nat values.
The way that worked for my was to replace the Nat values with 0 before the where() function.

```
df['date3']= df['date3'].fillna(0)
```

then use the `where()` function with conditions like `== 0 or >= 0`, and it worked for me.

and after that change back that column from `0` to `Nat`.

It's not a clean solution but it's something.

Hope It works.

The problem with this is that doesn't work with multiple conditions "&" in `where()` function, but it seems that it is not your case.